Angular router navigate is encoding the URL
This question has been asked before but I could not find a solution that works. I have a simple router.navigate in the code like below on a button click
this.router.navigate(['/bill-read'], { queryParams: { serialNumber: this.data?.SerialNumber }} );  

On button click I see the below encoded URL in the browser with error route not found
https://localhost:4200/bill-read%3FserialNumber%3DC22LU003183 
which when decoded looks like below
https://localhost:4200/bill-read?serialNumber=C22LU003183

I have also tried using navgiateByUrl but getting similar error
this.router.navigateByUrl('/bill-read?serialNumber='+ this.data?.SerialNumber );


A possible reason is you may have something wrong in ...routes.ts.

Your first attempt It's looks like ok. This stackblitz it's related to a different question but works. What version of Angular do you're using? can you edit your question adding the "APP_ROUTES"?

include routing for that component.  It could be you want: this.router.navigate(['/bill-read/' + this.data?.SerialNumber]);
